# Scraping dynamic website with Selenium/Beautiful Soup skips items

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping this [website](https://atlantelavoro.inapp.org/atlante_professioni.php) with a combination of Beautiful Soup and Selenium. The website has some dynamically loaded content which I need to scrape as well. Problem is not all data gets scraped, because some items are missing from the output, because they have the same name (but different content inside the links which need to be scraped as well). Here's my code:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

URL = "https://atlantelavoro.inapp.org/atlante_professioni.php"

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()), options=options)
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(URL)
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@role='button']")
for element in elements:
    action_chains.move_to_element(element).perform()
    element.click()

ue = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h4.panel-title4 a[role='button']")

for element in ue:
    action_chains.move_to_element(element).perform()
    element.click()


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
out = {}
tree = soup.find_all(class_="panel panel-info")

for leaf in tree:
    out[leaf.select_one(".panel-title").get_text(strip=True)] = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in leaf.select("h4.panel-title3 .ml-2")]
    if leaf.find_all("div", class_="panel-warning") != []:
        tutti = leaf.find_all("div", class_="panel-warning")[-1].select("div.panel-primary")
        ok = {}
        for t in tutti:
            ok[t.select_one("h4.panel-title4").get_text(strip=True)]= {e.get_text(strip=True): {} for e in t.select("h4.panel-title5")}

    for k, v in out.items():
        if v == []:
            out[k] = ["Sezione in aggiornamento"]
        elif v[-1] == "Tutti":
            v[v.index("Tutti")] = {"Tutti": ok}
```

This is a sample of the result I get (exported to json):

```
{
    "Agricoltura(20)": [
        "CCNL Agricoltura-Aziende in conto terzi del 21-06-2012",
        "CCNL Agricoltura-Operai e Florivivaisti (CGIL,CISL,UIL) del 25-05-2010",
        "CCNL Agricoltura-Operai e Florivivaisti (UGL) del 27-06-2011",
        "CCNL Aziende manutenzione del verde del 25-09-2008",
        {
            "Tutti": {
                "01.\nAgricoltura, silvicoltura e pesca(11)": {
                    "Addetto area della produzione": {},
                    "Addetto conduzione macchine agricole": {},
                    "Addetto conduzione macchine agricole (liv.2°)": {},
                    "Addetto in allevamenti": {},
                    "Addetto in aziende da latte e lattiero casearie": {},
                    "Addetto in aziende orto-floro-frutticole": {}
                },
                "24.\nArea comune(4)": {
                    "Addetto al controllo e gestione dell'attività di impresa": {},
                    "Addetto alle registrazioni ed ai servizi amministrativi": {},
                    "Addetto area contabile, amministrativa": {},
                    "Addetto svolgimento mansioni tecniche amministrative, contabili": {}
                },
                "02.\nProduzioni alimentari(4)": {
                    "Addetto in aziende viti-vinicole": {},
                    "Addetto in impresa multifunzionale": {}
                },
                "14.\nServizi digitali(1)": {
                    "Addetto area informatica": {}
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

Not gonna paste the rest of it cause it is kinda big, and it shows the issue exactly even with this small bit: where it says e.g. "01.\nAgricoltura, silvicoltura e pesca(11)", the number between brackets is the number of elements that it should have inside, but naturally it just skips the ones where the name is the same. To clarify even further this is my output:

```
{'Addetto area della produzione': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole (liv.2°)': {}, 'Addetto in allevamenti': {}, 'Addetto in aziende da latte e lattiero casearie': {}, 'Addetto in aziende orto-floro-frutticole': {}}
```

This is the desired output:

```
{'Addetto area della produzione': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole (liv.2°)': {}, 'Addetto in allevamenti': {}, 'Addetto in allevamenti': {}, 'Addetto in aziende da latte e lattiero casearie': {}, 'Addetto in aziende da latte e lattiero casearie': {}, 'Addetto in aziende orto-floro-frutticole': {}, 'Addetto in aziende orto-floro-frutticole': {}}
```

but of course I need the items that have the same name to get automatically renamed to something else e.g.

```
'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole-1': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole-2': {}, 'Addetto conduzione macchine agricole-3': {},
```

Is there a way to do this? Sorry for the long post, still getting the hang of this (I'd also need the links to be scraped and for the contents to go into the empty dicts but hey, question for another day :D )

Answer (score 0):

Try to scrape by `requests_html` and use `request.html.render(sleep = 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it! I just did:

```
for t in tutti:
        title4 = t.select_one("h4.panel-title4").get_text(strip=True)
        ok[title4] = {f"{e.get_text(strip=True)}_{i+1}": [] for i, e in enumerate(t.select("h4.panel-title5"))}
        links = [e.a.get("href") for e in t.select("h4.panel-title5")]
        for (i, link) in enumerate(links):
            links[i]="https://atlantelavoro.inapp.org" + link
        for (i, link) in enumerate(links):
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
            nostro = soup2.find(class_="row iq-font-blue mt-5 iq-fs-16 col-sm-12")
            title = f"{soup2.select_one('section.overview-block-ptb h2').text}_{i+1}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).